# Send mail to selected users

Tags: rules, javascript

I want to send mail on webform submission to selected users. Suppose I'm user and admin must select users from my account that if I submit webform, then how many user's can get that notifications of my webform submission via mail?

Answer (score 0):

Use simplenews module

[Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews)

> Simplenews publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers.
>   Both anonymous and authenticated users can opt-in to different mailing
>   lists. HTML email can be sent by adding Mime Mail module.
>
> Simplenews 7.x-1.0 has finally been released which includes a number
>   of other important bugfixes, especially in the upgrade path.
>
> Features Sending nodes as newsletters to subscribers Multiple
>   newsletter categories with separate settings Per category and
>   multi-signup Blocks and Pages Subscriber management including
>   mass-subscription and export Optional E-mail confirmations for
>   anonymous users Customizable newsletter templates Support for HTML
>   (including text alternative) newsletter when used in combination with
>   a supported mail system module Views and Rules integration Support for
>   multi-language newsletters

Comment: your welcome .if you find any difficulty let me know

Comment: Thanks for this Harshal, this requirement is done by rules and also by simplenews but i have some other difficulty and i have put that as question.